# autohide address bar issue

Tags: javascript, iphone, safari, hide, address-bar

I am hiding my address bar, in Safari on an iPhone using this script:

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
setTimeout(function(){
window.scrollTo(0, 1);
}, 0);
});
```

The problem is if the page doesn't fully load and the user scrolls down, when it finishes loading it shoots back up again. I want to make this more defensive, so when a user moves the phone and clears the address bar themselves, it will not do it again.

This was my attempt which didn't work:

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
setTimeout(function(){
  if(window > 1){

  }
  else
  {
window.scrollTo(0, 1);
}}, 0);
});
```

Just in case anyone says I was going to do a if(!window ... and take out the else but wanted to keep it like this for testing purposes, marks out the possibility of me writing it wrong.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `document.body.scrollTop` instead of simply `window`:

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (document.body.scrollTop > 1) {
            // Do your testing here...
        } else {
            window.scrollTo(0, 1);
        }
    }, 0);
});
```

---

When you're done testing, you could collapse it all into 1 line:

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.body.scrollTop || window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }, 0);
});
```